# Prove $|A| \le|C|$ for injection and surjective functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are finite sets with $F: A \to B$ a surjection and $G: B \to C$ an injection.

Prove $|A| \le |C|$

I could prove it using examples, but not sure how to generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true; set $B$ and $C$ to singletons.

Comment: you are totally right! what about |A| >= |C| ?

I believe that is true

Comment: $B$ can be a singleton and $A$ and $C$ any non-empty set. So no relations,